# Php file editor online

Tags: php, html, web, edit

I have some code like this in my `Index.php` file

```
<?php include 'config.php'; ?>
<div class="center">
  <div class="col-lg-4 callout">
        <h3><?php echo $servicetitle1 ?></h3>
        <p><?php echo $servicedesc1 ?></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

and I had another file called `config.php` that contained the `$` values such as

```
$servicetitle1  = "Title";
$servicedesc1   = "Description";
```

Could I in anyway have a 3rd php file that I could edit the values of the `config.php` file from, it would obviously be password protected.
One up on that idea, Could I overlay a menu over `index.php` where I could edit the values directly?

All of this is for a client that would like "Easy" editing of his site. 
I know this is alot like WordPress and that is the way i am going without actually making a WordPress theme, Please also keep in mind that this applies to the whole page down to images but I'm sure that it can't be too hard to scale?

Comment: Normally what a database is for.

Comment: Yeah i know but i have spent ages developing the website now in PHP and just realized :/ re doing the whole page would result in a loss of profit!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could, but you need forms for that. PHP is a server-side language, so when your webpage loads, it is already calculated. To change the values of your variables, you will need html forms posting to another URL that will trigger backend code that will make the changes.

Comment: Forms are what i was thinking on the 3rd PHP file, Could you please elaborate on "Forms posting to another URL"? Thanks!

Comment: Sure! Well, at first you need to set routes for your application. You might need a framework to help you do that. I am not very aware of PHP frameworks but I've heard that Laravel is quite used. After having a route, you need an html <form method="post" action="YOUR ROUTE HERE"> tag containing the fields you wish to update.

Comment: Great! Thankyou That makes more sense now, i will look into this method.